# Automatic login in net2ftp

Tags: php, ftp, ftp-client

I have a ftp client ([net2ftp](http://www.net2ftp.com/)) embeded to a html page to upload files.
Now this file uploader comes with a login sistem. There is a way to set something like an auto login? 
Let me set this more clearly, when my user comes to the net2ftp login page he/she is already logged in my main page, so its pointless for him/her to log again. So I want to find a way to make the net2ftp log automatically with the user's credentials.

I apologize if this text seems a bit confusing, english is not my native language.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally solve it. It was pretty easy actually.

For the autologin in net2ftp you need to go to 'net2ftp/files_to_upload/includes/registerglobals.inc.php', you'll see there is an array called net2ftp_globals, as its name sugests, it contains all the global vars, including the server and user name, languaje and skin options, etc.

You need to set the following vars this way:

> $net2ftp_globals["ftpserver"] = [your ftp server name]
>
> $net2ftp_globals["username"] = [your username]
>
> $net2ftp_globals["password_encrypted"]  = [your password]

then, in the same class, you need to change this vars

> $net2ftp_globals["state"] = "browse"
>
> $net2ftp_globals["state2"] = "main"

This way, net2ftp is going to be redirected to contents table and will skip the login page.

Keep in mind this only works is you have a ftp configuration for user, if you have users with more than one ftp server this is not a good solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an easier way to do this as of 2018(and more reliable I think).

On version 1.1 of net2ftp there is an option to bookmark a directory which creates a direct link to any directory you wish, automatically logs the user in and bypasses the login page. The link comes in this format:

https://example.com/admin/ftp/index.php?protocol=FTP&ftpserver=ftp.localhost&ftpserverport=21&sshfingerprint=&username=[username]&password_encrypted=[encrypted_password]&language=en&skin=shinra&ftpmode=automatic&passivemode=no&viewmode=list&sort=&sortorder=&state=browse&state2=main&directory=%2Fpublic_html%&entry=

You can then put an iframe on your page like this:

```
<iframe src="admin/ftp/index.php?[The rest of the link is the same as above]></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

So let me get this straight, the user is already logged in onto your site, but will then need to log in into net2ftp?

Well, if your site is servicing this net2ftp service, and their login credentials for net2ftp are the same as your site, why don't you just alter the embed form code to have their credentials echo'd into the login fields? Does that work, or are you wanting to avoid the login feature entirely?

Perhaps submitting a link to your site would help.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, I want net2ftp to log with the user's credentials. I was thinking in using the $_SESSION vars (im using PHP) to log the user to net2ftp. Is this ok or it can have some security problems? Thanks!

Comment: I'd imagine that's totally possible, but having them log-in without having to click 'Log In' is another issue... I suppose that's a question for net2ftp support then. Sorry I couldn't help more!